# Is the empty set a strict order?

Tags: order-theory

I've read that it is a total order, but is it strict on the empty set? I think this may be vacuously true, but I don't know if that is true.

Comment: Yes, it's vacuously true.  Why do you doubt it?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand how to prove something is vacuously true.

Comment: Just check the handful of properties that define strict order. Essentially, any statement that starts with $\forall c\in\emptyset$ is vacuously true

Comment: A statement is vacuous if it doesn't apply to anything -- "vacuous" and "vacuum" have the same root.  Such a statement must be true because there can't be any counterexample.  So as Hagen von Eitzen has said, any statement about all the elements of the empty set must be vacuously true.

Comment: A minor amendation to saulspatz' comment: any *universal* claim about the elements of the emptyset. "Every element of the emptyset is [---]" is automatically true, while "some element of the emptyset is [---]" is automatically false.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks.  I amended my comment to reflect yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments above.*

---

Yes, this is vacuously true.

In fact, any claim of the form "Every element of the empty set is [---]" is automatically true, while "some element of the empty set is [---]" is automatically false.